# SpringBoot Artemis Durable Subscription

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to get durable subscriptions working with Springboot and Artemis.

I have one application configured as a publisher and two subscribers running under Docker like so:

```
version: '3'
services:
    amq:
        image: "vromero/activemq-artemis"
        environment:
            - TZ=Australia/Sydney
            - ARTEMIS_USERNAME=admin
            - ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - "8161:8161"
            - "61616:61616"
    pub:
        image: "amqdemo:latest"
        environment:
            - TZ=Australia/Sydney
            - SPRING_ARTEMIS_HOST=amq
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=publisher
            - CLIENT_ID=pub
            - MAX_SEND=1
        depends_on:
            - amq
    sub1:
        image: "amqdemo:latest"
        environment:
            - TZ=Australia/Sydney
            - SPRING_ARTEMIS_HOST=amq
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=subscriber1
            - CLIENT_ID=sub1
        depends_on:
            - amq
            - pub
    sub2:
        image: "amqdemo:latest"
        environment:
            - TZ=Australia/Sydney
            - SPRING_ARTEMIS_HOST=amq
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=subscriber2
            - CLIENT_ID=sub2
        depends_on:
            - amq
            - pub
```

The main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
public class AmqdemoApplication {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Value("${CLIENT_ID}")
    private String clientId;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AmqdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper geObjMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> factory(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

// TODO - not durable
//      factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);

        connectionFactory.setClientId(clientId);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Everybody is happy. Publisher sends and subscribers receive their topics:

```
pub_1   | Sending a message.
sub1_1  | 2021-01-13 14:58:28.463  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.amqdemo.Topic1Receiver       : Message read from topic 1 : CustomMessage{text='Topic 1 message', sequence=1, secret=false, sent=2021-01-13T14:58:28.456582} transfer time: 7070µs
sub2_1  | 2021-01-13 14:58:28.470  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.amqdemo.Topic2Receiver       : Message read from topic 2 : CustomMessage{text='Topic 2 message', sequence=1, secret=false, sent=2021-01-13T14:58:28.463210} transfer time: 7489µs
```

As soon as I uncomment the setSubscriptionDurable, the subscribers no longer receive messages.

I have found many references to the need to set the clientId, but I have set the clientId. I have tried various settings on the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory and the CachingConnectionFactory to no avail.

[Here is the full source](https://github.com/zorro2b/artemis-springboot) for the example I am working on

It works as is with DURABLE=false in the docker-compose.yml. Set it to true and it no longer works.

I have also tried various permutations of PUB_SUB_DOMAIN true/false with no positive effect.

If I set DURABLE=true and PUB_SUB_DOMAIN=true for all containers, then the queues look like this:

[image]

It seems the messages are being queued up on topic1, but the subscriber is listening on sub1.topic1 which has no messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then problem is that you need to set the pubSub domain both on connectionFactory:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
public class AmqdemoApplication {
    // ...
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> factory(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(pubSubDomain); // <--- HERE
        factory.setClientId(clientId);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(durable);
        connectionFactory.setClientId(clientId);

        return factory;
    }
    // ...
```

and jmsTemplate:

```java
@Component
@Profile("publisher")
public class ScheduleConfig {
    // ...
    public ScheduleConfig(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true); // <--- HERE
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I code as per your example, I get:
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
factory.setClientId("ConsumerA");

If I add:
connectionFactory.setClientId(clientId);

the error goes away, but the subscribers don't receive any messages.

Comment: Does it work using the string "ConsumerA" as clientId or any other hard coded string? Which error are you talking about? Keep in mind that the clientId can't be null or empty and in that case you should see a warning message in the application's logs. Most probably you should use something like `@Value("${services.sub1.environment.CLIENT_ID}")` as key.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste problem. That should have read, I get:
 Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'topic1' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: setClientID call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'clientId' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead.

Comment: I have tried setting a hardcoded string for the client id with no success. I have also tried running only a single subscriber container, but still no progress.

Comment: I have added the example to Github and linked it in the question for clarity.

Comment: I have integrated my answer after reviewing your code.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!